# Itext com Firebase no Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, itext

Olá, pessoal, tudo bem? Me surgiu uma dúvida aqui que gostaria que ajudassem a saná-la. É possível gerar um relatório em PDF com itext que conste dados do Firebase. Tipo, cadastro vários clientes durante a semana no Firebase e no final da semana é gerado um relatório automático para mim com os clientes cadastrados e seus dados. Obrigado pela ajuda desde já.

Comment: Resposta curta: Sim, é possível,